# LeaderboardAPI : I want to show only Today's record by comparing it with the created date

Tags: python, django

**My Modely.py**
I am storing playername, TotalPoints, created_date by POST API

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

# Create your models here.

class leaderboard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("playername"), max_length=255)
    TotalPoints = models.IntegerField(_("TotalPoints"))
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

### My Serializers.py file:

This is my Searializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import leaderboard



class leaderboardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = leaderboard
        fields = [
            'name',
            'TotalPoints',
            ]


class lwithcdateSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = leaderboard
        fields = [
            'name',
            'TotalPoints',
            'created_date',
            ]
```

---

### My Views

```
class Leaderboard(APIView):

    def get(self, request, formate=None, **kwargs):
            today = datetime.date.today()
            serializer = lwithcdateSerializers(leaderb.objects.all().order_by('-TotalPoints') 
             [:40], many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Please check the above code and let me know how can I display only Today's record

Answer (score 0):

You need to **filter** on `created_date` column.

```
serializer = lwithcdateSerializers(leaderb.objects.filter(created_date__date=today).order_by('-TotalPoints')
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works, I was confused about how to make comparisons , you made it clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers